# "file already used by another program" writing error

Tags: c#, .net

i keep getting this error "file already use by another program" whenever i try to write to an already opened file, although i used the "close()" and "flush()" commands, it still gives me the error, here is my code:

```
private void Openbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open GSMB File";
        ofd.Filter = "GSMB Files (*.gsmb)|*.gsmb|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File opened Succesfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.Unicode);
            BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.Unicode);
            brs.BaseStream.Position = 0x4;
            menuItem9.Text = brs.ReadInt32().ToString();
            if (menuItem9.Text == "3620")
            {
                num_pointers = 204;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "54662")
            {
                num_pointers = 2372;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "9560")
            {
                num_pointers = 88;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "1126")
            {
                num_pointers = 130;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "342")
            {
                num_pointers = 16;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "6232")
            {
                num_pointers = 467;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "75698")
            {
                num_pointers = 498;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "9914")
            {
                num_pointers = 110;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "128")
            {
                num_pointers = 4;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "5394")
            {
                num_pointers = 156;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "12000")
            {
                num_pointers = 580;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a Pokémon Typing Adventure string file !", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
            int startstr = 0x1C;
            br.BaseStream.Position = startstr;
            int startstrval = br.ReadInt32();
            for (int i = 4; i < (num_pointers * 4 + 1); i += 4)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Position = startstr + i;
                offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32() + startstrval);
            }
            Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
            {
                int currentOffset = offsets[i];

                int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

                int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;

                br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;

                var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
                values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
            }
            foreach (int offset in offsets)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
             listView1.Items[offset].SubItems[1].Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\n");
            }

            br.Close();
            br = null;
        }
        ofd.Dispose();
        ofd = null;
    }
private void menuItem10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));

        bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x20;
        int number_pointers = Convert.ToInt32(num_pointers);
        Encoding enc = Encoding.Unicode;

        bw.Write(number_pointers);

        int curr_pointer = 4 + number_pointers * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(curr_pointer);
            curr_pointer += enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text) + 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
            bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + '\0'));

        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        bw = null;
    }
```

thank you, and i apologize for any disturbance.
PS: please do not post usless comments and answers such as "seach in google", "we already answered these types of questions", etc...
i spent 5 hours looking in google for an answer and nothing came up but using the ofd.close(), and i searched also in the stackoverflow website for similiar question, same answer, thank you.

Comment: do you get the error the first time you open the file? or only on subsequent times?

Comment: Where in your code the error is happening?  It is happening in menuItem10_Click or in Openbtn_Click

Comment: Have you also tried closing your "brs" `BinaryReader` variable? I don't see it being closed in your first method.

Comment: Ichabod Clay, thank you sir, i forgot about that one, thanks to for everyone else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no exception handling inside this function, if an exception occurs, it won't continue, therefore never execute the `br.Close();` function.

You should use `try { } finally { }` to ensure it's closed.

```
private void Openbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Title = "Open GSMB File";
    ofd.Filter = "GSMB Files (*.gsmb)|*.gsmb|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try {
            MessageBox.Show("File opened Succesfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            path = ofd.FileName;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.Unicode);
            BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path), Encoding.Unicode);
            brs.BaseStream.Position = 0x4;
            menuItem9.Text = brs.ReadInt32().ToString();
            if (menuItem9.Text == "3620")
            {
                num_pointers = 204;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "54662")
            {
                num_pointers = 2372;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "9560")
            {
                num_pointers = 88;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "1126")
            {
                num_pointers = 130;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "342")
            {
                num_pointers = 16;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "6232")
            {
                num_pointers = 467;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "75698")
            {
                num_pointers = 498;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "9914")
            {
                num_pointers = 110;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "128")
            {
                num_pointers = 4;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "5394")
            {
                num_pointers = 156;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else if (menuItem9.Text == "12000")
            {
                num_pointers = 580;
                menuItem8.Text = num_pointers.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a Pokémon Typing Adventure string file !", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
            int startstr = 0x1C;
            br.BaseStream.Position = startstr;
            int startstrval = br.ReadInt32();
            for (int i = 4; i < (num_pointers * 4 + 1); i += 4)
            {
                br.BaseStream.Position = startstr + i;
                offsets.Add(br.ReadInt32() + startstrval);
            }
            Dictionary<int, string> values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Count; i++)
            {
                int currentOffset = offsets[i];

                int nextOffset = (i + 1) < offsets.Count ? offsets[i + 1] : (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

                int stringLength = (nextOffset - currentOffset - 1) / 2;

                br.BaseStream.Position = currentOffset;

                var chars = br.ReadChars(stringLength);
                values.Add(currentOffset, new String(chars));
            }
            foreach (int offset in offsets)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(offset.ToString("X")).SubItems.Add(values[offset]);
             listView1.Items[offset].SubItems[1].Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\n");
            }               
        }
        finally {
            br.Close();
            br = null;
        }
    }
    ofd.Dispose();
    ofd = null;
}
private void menuItem10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    BinaryWriter bw;
    try {
        bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));

        bw.BaseStream.Position = 0x20;
        int number_pointers = Convert.ToInt32(num_pointers);
        Encoding enc = Encoding.Unicode;

        bw.Write(number_pointers);

        int curr_pointer = 4 + number_pointers * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(curr_pointer);
            curr_pointer += enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text) + 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number_pointers; i++)
            bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + '\0'));
    }
    finally {
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        bw = null;
    }
}
```

I'm also not sure if you should show a msgbox that shows "file opened succesfully " right at the beginning of your logic.

Answer (score 1):

all disposable objects should be used if possible in a `using` - statement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

if you would put all your disposable objects (BinaryReader, FileStream etc) into such a statement, it would work

Answer (score 1):

The likely culprit is your own program!

As user287107 said, if you dispose of your handle to the file, you should be able to open it again for writing later.

Also, sircapsalot has a good suggestion: make sure that everything is disposed of properly by using try {} finally {}.

Comment: you are right, i forgot about another binaryreader command. ty :)